# Unsupported depth of input image: 'VDepth::contains(depth)' where 'depth' is 4 (CV_32S)

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to process some images in OpenCV. Specifically, swapping color panes using the following functions.

```
def green_ble_swap(image)
    im_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    im_copy = np.copy(im_rgb)
    blue = im_copy[:,:,2].copy()
    green = im_copy[:,:,1].copy()
    im_copy[:,:,2] = green
    im_copy[:,:,1] = blue
    return im_copy
```

However I get the following error.

```
> Unsupported depth of input image:
>     'VDepth::contains(depth)'
> where
>     'depth' is 4 (CV_32S)
```

Not sure whats the error here.

Comment: is the error arise from cvtcolor function? if so whats the depth of input image?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're encountering the error because you're trying to perform a 3-channel operation on a 4-channel image. Specifically, the error comes from trying to convert a `BGR` image to `RGB` when the input image has a transparent channel. The correct method would be to do `cv2.COLOR_BGRA2RGB` instead of `cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB`. You can swap the blue and green channels in-place using `cv2.split()` to obtain the `BGR` channels (for 3-channel image) and `BGRA` channels for (4-channel image) then swap the channels using Numpy indexing. You also need to use the `cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED` flag when loading the image or the alpha channel will be dropped. Example:

Input `->` Output

[image]
[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def green_blue_swap(image):
    # 3-channel image (no transparency)
    if image.shape[2] == 3:
        b,g,r = cv2.split(image)
        image[:,:,0] = g
        image[:,:,1] = b
    # 4-channel image (with transparency)
    elif image.shape[2] == 4:
        b,g,r,a = cv2.split(image)
        image[:,:,0] = g
        image[:,:,1] = b
    return image 

# Load image
image = cv2.imread('1.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
cv2.imshow('image', image)

# Swap channels
swapped = green_blue_swap(image)
cv2.imshow('swapped', swapped)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: It looks like this is the case.